# Updating go websocket library to latest version

Tags: websocket, package, go

I am running the Go compiler on Ubuntu, installed using `sudo apt-get install golang`

I've successfully compiled and executed the code for a *Trivial example server* (See http://golang.org/pkg/websocket/#Handler )

```
package main

import (
    "http"
    "io"
    "websocket"
)

// Echo the data received on the Web Socket.
func EchoServer(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    io.Copy(ws, ws);
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/echo", websocket.Handler(EchoServer));
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":12345", nil);
    if err != nil {
        panic("ListenAndServe: " + err.String())
    }
}
```

However, I fail to connect to the server with my version of Chromium (16.0.912.77). I assume Chrome has implemented the RFC 6455 Websocket (version 13), but that the go websocket library in the Ubuntu *golang* package is out of date.

So, my question is: How can I update only the websocket package to the latest version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the Go `websocket` package is `net/websocket` at `code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket`, which requires the Go 1 weekly development release.

For Ubuntu golang-weekly: [Ubuntu PPA packages for Go](https://launchpad.net/~niemeyer/+ppa-packages).

For weekly development release documentation: [Go Programming Language](http://weekly.golang.org/).

Comment: This was the information I really needed. Thanks a lot for the help. Now I have a more recent version which seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the version of Go in Ubuntu package repository is probably r60.3 (or so), which is a bit old now. Use latest weekly, change the code to:

```
package main

import (
        "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
        "io"
        "net/http"
)

// Echo the data received on the Web Socket.
func EchoServer(ws *websocket.Conn) {
        io.Copy(ws, ws)
}

func main() {
        http.Handle("/echo", websocket.Handler(EchoServer))
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":12345", nil)
        if err != nil {
                panic("ListenAndServe: " + err.Error())
        }
}
```

Moreover in the websocket package `s/ParseRequestURI/ParseRequest/`, then it seems to work here.(**1**)

**Update**: Sorry, I wrote/read too fast, it doesn't seem to work, the page shows: "not websocket protocol" (here is Chrome 18.0.1025.33 beta on 64b Ubuntu 10.04)

**Update 2012-08-22**: The above (**1**) note about editing the websocket package doesn't hold anymore. The websocket package has been meanwhile updated and the example (main) code above now compiles w/o problems. Anyway, I haven't tested if it afterwards does what is should or not, sorry.

Comment: And thanks to you too. It was really useful to get an update on what changes needed to be made to the code for the new version.

Comment: A note on the "not websocket protocol". I got it to work fine using a `ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1/echo');` command in the Chrome console. But yes, in order to make the websocket library compile, you needed to change the ParseRequestURI to ParseRequest as you mentioned.

Comment: How do I get documentation on items in the Repo that are new...such as the new websocket?  On the ListenAndServe function, I use to be able to call .String() but now it complains about it not having such a function.

Comment: Online docs for e.g. http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse?repo=net are here: http://gopkgdoc.appspot.com/pkg/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket as seen here: http://weekly.golang.org/ref/

Comment: Thanks jnml. Not sure I would have found that otherwise.

Comment: What's the meaning of "s/ParseRequestURI/ParseRequest/" ?

Comment: @hardPass: Replace "ParseRequestURI" with "ParseRequest" expressed in 'sed' (vim, ...) notation. The 's' before the pattern means 'substitute' AFAIK.

Comment: @jnml, you're right. But I still don't understand. ParseRequestURI is a method of url, and url have no method named ParseRequest. Is there something I missed?

Comment: @hardPass: Dunno, perhaps force-reload the web-browser page? Anyway, today's update reads like "The above (1) note about editing the websocket package doesn't hold anymore. The websocket package has been meanwhile updated and the example (main) code above now compiles w/o problems. Anyway, I haven't tested if it afterwards does what is should or not, sorry." HTH